# Убрать div с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Вообщем при выборе radio нужно асинхронно убрать блок div, не получается. Вот:

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <label for="rrr"><input id="rrr" type="radio" class="tr" name="dostavka" value="<?=$item['dostavka_id']?>" /><?=$item['name']?></label>

</form>
```

Что нужно удалить:

```
 <div class="notauth">
            <label>ФИО:</label> <input class="zakaz-inpt" type="text" name="name_zakaz">
   </div>
```

Вот что написал :

```
  $(".tr").click(function(e){       
      var rrr = $("#rrr").val();
        $.ajax({
           url: './',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {rrr: rrr},
           success: function(res){
                if(res == 1){                
                    $(".notauth").fadeOut(500);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".notauth").remove();
                    }, 500);
                }else{

                }
           },
           error: function(){
                alert("Error!");
           }
        });
    });
```

Чет не получается удалить таким кодом js, в ajax я слаб, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри, что у тебя приходит в res, мне кажется, что проверка if/else некорректная, поэтому блок не удаляётся.

Если убрать проверку, то всё будет ок:

```
success: function(res){       
  $(".notauth").fadeOut(500); // скрываем
  setTimeout(function() { // удаляем
    $(".notauth").remove();
  }, 500);
```

Исходник тут: https://jsfiddle.net/octav47/93ncjyuz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tr").click(function(e){       
      var rrr = $("#rrr").val();
        $.ajax({
           url: './',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {rrr: rrr},
           success: function(){ $(".notauth").fadeOut(500); },
           error: function(){
                alert("Error!");
           }
        });
    });
```